# Filter for events that occur within a time range of event "A" in r

Tags: r

I would like to be able to filter all "B" events that happened within 5 seconds prior to event "A". Not even sure where to start. Here is some sample data.

```
set.seed(123)
event_df <- tibble(time_sec = c(1:120)) %>% 
  sample_n(50) %>%
  arrange(time_sec) %>% 
  mutate(event = sample(c("A","B"), 
                        size = 50, 
                        replace = TRUE, 
                        prob = c(0.1,0.9)))
```

Expected output would be along the lines of

```
tribble(
  ~time_sec,  ~event,
  57, "B",
  90, "B",
  91, "B",
  92, "B",
  103, "B",
)
```

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You have 45 'B' and 5 'A' values..  So, which element is getting compared

Comment: All "B" events that happened within 5 seconds prior to an "A" event.

Comment: Are those values correct in the expected.  I was thinking `event_df %>% group_by(grp =  lag(cumsum(event == 'A'), default = 0)) %>% filter((last(time_sec) - time_sec) <=5) %>% slice(1)`

Comment: I didn't include all the results, just the first few. The "A" events are at 60, 93, 99, 107, 115 seconds, so I want to grab all "B" events between 55-60, 88-93, 94-99, and 102-107 seconds.

Comment: If that is the case you can remove the `slice` i.e. `event_df %>% group_by(grp =  lag(cumsum(event == 'A'), default = 0)) %>% filter((last(time_sec) - time_sec) <=5)`

Comment: I am not getting any error.  Please check the output below

Comment: Yeah, I noticed an error on my end and deleted comment. So based on your comments this does the trick: event_df %>% group_by(grp = lag(cumsum(event == 'A'), default = 0)) %>% 
  filter((last(time_sec) - time_sec) <=5) %>% 
  filter(event == "B")

Comment: In the below, I didn't use the `filter(event == 'B')` to show the values of 'A' as welll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `dplyr` would be to create a grouping column based on the occurence of 'A' values in 'event', get the `lag` of it so that each block will have both preceding 'B' values and the `last` value as 'A', then we do the `filter` by taking the difference of the 'time_sec' where it is 'A' (`last` value) with that of all others and check if it is less than or equal to 5

```
library(dplyr)
event_df %>%
    group_by(grp =  lag(cumsum(event == 'A'), default = 0)) %>% 
    filter((last(time_sec) - time_sec) <=5)
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   grp [6]
#   time_sec event   grp
#      <int> <chr> <dbl>
# 1       57 B         0
# 2       60 A         0
# 3       90 B         1
# 4       91 B         1
# 5       92 B         1
# 6       93 A         1
# 7       96 B         2
# 8       98 B         2
# 9       99 A         2
#10      103 B         3
#11      107 A         3
#12      113 B         4
#13      115 A         4
#14      117 B         5
```

Comment: I've run into some issues and as you answered this one correctly I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222140/filter-for-events-that-occur-within-a-time-range-of-event-a-in-r-part-2 If you wouldn't mind looking at it I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @seansteele sure will take a look

Answer (score 0):

One way using base R would be to get corresponding `time_sec` value where `event == 'A'` and from `event_df` select only those rows that have `time_sec` less than 5 seconds.

```
A_event <- event_df$time_sec[event_df$event == 'A']
subset(event_df, time_sec %in% c(sapply(A_event, `-`, 1:5)) & event == 'B')

#  time_sec event
#     <int> <chr>
#1       57 B    
#2       90 B    
#3       91 B    
#4       92 B    
#5       96 B    
#6       98 B    
#7      103 B    
#8      113 B
```