# Filter for events that occur within a time range of event “A” in r part 2

Tags: r, time

This is a follow up to a question asked previously ([Filter for events that occur within a time range of event "A" in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64996776/filter-for-events-that-occur-within-a-time-range-of-event-a-in-r)). Since the original post was answered correctly  I decided to start a new question. If this is improper let me know.

Quick recap. I have event data with a second value. I wanted to filter all B events that came 5 seconds prior to all A events.

The issue I've run into is that the data is split into periods and the seconds restart. I didn't think this would be an issue as the data was sorted, so didn't include a periods column in my original question, but there as been some unexpected results.

Here is a sample of data with the addition of a period column.

```
set.seed(123)
event_df <- tibble(time_sec = c(1:120)) %>% 
  sample_n(100) %>%
  mutate(period = sample(c(1,2,3),
                       size = 100,
                       replace = TRUE),
         event = sample(c("A","B"), 
                        size = 100, 
                        replace = TRUE, 
                        prob = c(0.1,0.9))) %>% 
  select(period, time_sec, event) %>% 
  arrange(period, time_sec)
```

When using the solution that originally worked...

```
event_df %>%
  group_by(grp =  lag(cumsum(event == 'A'), default = 0)) %>% 
  filter((last(time_sec) - time_sec) <=5)
```

... you'll notice that it works correctly except for the first A event of each period grabs all the B events in the prior period regardless of the time. For example, grp 4 looks like this:

```
~period, ~time_sec, ~event, ~grp
1        111,       "B"    4
1        114,       "B"    4
1        120,       "B"    4
2        79,        "B"    4
2        83,        "A"    4
```

Expected output for grp 4 would be:

```
~period, ~time_sec, ~event, ~grp
2        79,        "B"    4
2        83,        "A"    4
```

I tried grouping by period thinking this would solve the issue, and while it filtered out most of the events, it still took the last event from the previous period.

```
event_df %>%
  group_by(period,
           grp =  lag(cumsum(event == 'A'), default = 0)) %>% 
  filter((last(time_sec) - time_sec) <=5)
```

Results in:

```
~period, ~time_sec, ~event, ~grp
1        120,       "B"    4
2        79,        "B"    4
2        83,        "A"    4
```

Closer, but still grabbing the last event from the previous period.

Update: Realized that the numbers were included because they time diff was a negative number. This solves it except there is a final grouping with no A event.

```
event_df %>%
  group_by(grp =  lag(cumsum(event == 'A'), default = 0)) %>% 
  filter((last(time_sec) - time_sec) <=5 & (last(time_sec) - time_sec) >= 0 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you added `period` to `group_by()` your `grp` values cross `period` values. So if the period doesn't end in an event "A" it uses an event "B" value for `last(time_sec)-time_sec`. So it always returns the final value in the period and any other "B" events within 5 seconds of it. A simple solution (works for the toy data, not sure on the real data) is modify the `filter()` command to make sure we're getting the true `last` value (which is the only event "A" in the `grp`):

```
event_df %>%
  group_by(grp =  lag(cumsum(event == 'A'), default = 0), period) %>% 
  filter((last(time_sec[event=='A']) - time_sec) <=5)
```

This works because the value of `last(time_sec[event=='A'])` is `NA` if there are no event "A" observations in the `period, grp` pair.

Answer (score 1):

This works too. A cheating version where I chop off anything after the last "A" event.

```
event_df %>% 
  slice(1:max(which(event=="A"))) %>% 
  group_by(grp = lag(cumsum(event == 'A'), default = 0)) %>% 
  filter((last(time_sec) - time_sec) <=5 & (last(time_sec) - time_sec) >= 0)
```